# testing angular service internal method calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following simple service

```
app.factory('Shoes', function() {
    function a() {return 12;}
    function b() {return a();}

    return {
      a: a,
      b: b
    }
  })
```

I want to test if the method `a` is being called when I call method `b`. My test looks like this:

```
describe('Testing a Shoes service', function() {
  var service;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(Shoes) {
    service = Shoes;
  }))

  it('.b should call .a', function() {
    spyOn(service, 'a');
    service.b();
    expect(service.a).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })

});
```

But the tests fail. Relevant plunker is [here](https://plnkr.co/sfXoq0).

**Question is how can I test this kind of interactions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is that you set on a spy on `service.a` method, but the internal `a` (which is called internally by `b`) is still the same internal method (i.e not the spy), that's why your test fail.

If you really want to do that, the only way is to not call the internal `a` but the method of your service:

```
app.factory('Shoes', function() {
    return {
        a: function a() {
            return 12;
        },

        b: function b() {
            return this.a();
        }
    };
});
```

Here is an update of your plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/6FZptdcX9qwyOE6kbgAX

EDIT:

Just some explanation: the `service.a` method is just a pointer to the internal `a` method. When you say `spyOn(service, 'a')`, you are just overwriting the `service.a` pointer to point to a completely different method (i.e a spy created by jasmine). The internal `a` method is private and will be never updated, so if you call `a()` in your internal `b` method, you just call the original method `a` not the spy pointed by `service.a`.

Comment: why the spy is not created for the function that the `service.a` references?

Comment: reasonable. please see follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222909/why-jasmine-spy-doesnt-resolve-the-function-object-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue with the following code

```
app.factory('Shoes', function() {
    var module = {
      a:function(){
        return 12;
      },
      b: function(){
        return this.a();
      }
    }
    return module;
});
```

It seems like your tested module can't just call a "function". It should call the **method**  of the object returned;

Updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/DeDmdQq3rguO6uGHElW6?p=preview

Comment: why the spy is not created for the function that the `service.a` references? shouldn't the references be resolved to original functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.factory('Shoes', function() {

var self = {
  a: function() {return 12;},
  b: function() {return this.a();}
}

return {
  a: self.a,
  b: self.b
}
})
```

I believe that's because b is not calling the function you are spying on. With factory above test passes.

Comment: why the spy is not created for the function that the `service.a` references? shouldn't the references be resolved to original functions?

Comment: spyOn(service, 'a') - creates new spy function on the place of service.a, while when b  functions is called it calls internal function a that exists in same scope, and not a spy that was created by jasmine, basically what Mickael said in answer above. That's how I, personally, see this problem.