# Why jasmine spy doesn't resolve the function object by reference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have the following simple service

```
app.factory('Shoes', function() {
    function a() {return 12;}
    function b() {return a();}

    return {
      a: a,
      b: b
    }
  })
```

I want to test if the method `a` is being called when I call method `b`. My test looks like this:

```
describe('Testing a Shoes service', function() {
  var service;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(Shoes) {
    service = Shoes;
  }))

  it('.b should call .a', function() {
    spyOn(service, 'a');
    service.b();
    expect(service.a).toHaveBeenCalled();
  })

});
```

But the tests fail. Relevant plunker is [here](https://plnkr.co/sfXoq0). I've already know how to resolve the problem in the plunker from [those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222079/testing-angular-service-internal-method-calls). Still there is one unresolved question:

**Why does the original function object is not being resolved?**

I thought that the system works like this (assuming spyies decorate the function with additional logic)

When I have no spies when I call `service.a` it's being resolved as:

```
A) service.a -> a()
```

and when I create a spy, it decorates the function

```
B) spy -> service.a => service.a*()
```

but the `service.a` is basically a reference for original `a()` so we should have a spy set for resolved function object in the end:

```
A + B => spy -> service.a -> a => a*()
```

Comment: `spyOn(service, 'a');` basically assigns a new value to `service.a`, e.g. `service.a = spyFunction;`. It doesn't change `a` itself, which is referenced by `b`. Everything in JavaScript is call/pass by value. Assigning a new value to a property does not magically change the value of a variable (i.e. assigning to `service.a` doesn't magically change the value of the variable `a`) (exceptions are global environment and `with` statements).

Answer (score 3):

After you call `spyOn(service, 'a')`, `service.a` is no longer the `a` you defined in the function -- it is a spy function. That spy function happens to call `a`, but it *is not `a`*; it has a different identity and is a different function.

However, setting the `a` property of `service` does not change the `function a` you declared inside `app.factory`. You've simply changed `service` so that its `a` property no longer refers to your original `a`. By contrast, your `b` function never changes its reference to the original `a`. It gets `a` straight from the local `app.factory` scope in which `a` and `b` were originally declared. The fact that `service` replaces its original `a` with a spy does not affect `b`'s call to `a()`, because it does not refer to `service.a`.